# Some attributes not working with Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I'm using this theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` but I faced some difficulty because I'm new with MaterialComponents.

Look at `colorControlNormal, colorButtonNormal, colorSwitchThumbNormal, colorBackgroundFloating` it's not working with `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`

```
    <style name="Theme.Test" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- The color applied to framework controls in their normal state. -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#EF5350</item>
        <!-- The color applied to framework controls in their activated (ex. checked) state. -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#AB47BC</item>
        <!-- The color applied to framework control highlights (ex. ripples, list selectors). -->
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#42A5F5</item>
        <!-- The color applied to framework buttons in their normal state. -->
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#66BB6A</item>
        <!-- The color applied to framework switch thumbs in their normal state. -->
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#FFCA28</item>
        <!-- Default color of background imagery for floating components, ex. dialogs, popups, and cards. -->
        <item name="colorBackgroundFloating">#5C1212</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` then you should use colour components like this

```
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
```

Instead of

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#EF5350</item>
```